# TypeScript/Javascript : adding a while loop anywhere in code causes an Uncaught Type error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I don't understand this at all. Adding a while loop causes a variable to throw an "Uncaught type error cannot read property of 'perp'". I tried many solutions, separating code, adding additional typing, trying to make :any type, I am truly at a loss.

Little background info: I am trying to make a quick little game called "Three's a Crime", essentially I have an algorithm that displays up to 3 criminals, at most 2 of them may be the actual perpetrators.

All the code is publicly view-able: https://github.com/treehau5/ThreesACrime

```
function main(num) {
    var is_over = false;
    var game = new GameObject.Game(shuffled_criminals, num);

    $('body').append(game.display());
    $("#status").text("Turn in progress");
    $('body').append('<div class="container"><p>Enter your guess<p><div class="input-append" id="turn_form"><form>\
         <input class="span2" id="Text1" type="text" />\
         <button class="btn" id="Button1" type="button">Go!</button>\
         </form>\
     </div></div>');

    console.log(game.getThree());
    while (true)          //removing this while loop causes above line to work fine.
    { }
}
```

here is the getThree method within the game class

```
       getThree() {
        var result: Criminal[] = [];
        var temp: Criminal[] = _.shuffle(this.criminals);
        var num_perp = 0;
        while (result.length != 3) {
            while ((num_perp != 3) && (result.length != 3)) {
                var x: Criminal = temp.pop();
                result.push(x);
                if (x.perp == true)
                    num_perp++;
                temp = _.shuffle(temp);
            }
            do {
                temp = _.shuffle(temp);
                var y: Criminal = temp.pop();
                if (y.perp == false)
                    result.push(y);
            }
            while (result.length != 3)

        }

        return result;
    }//end displayThree
```

I am using underscorejs for the shuffling, and the DefinitelyTyped underscore typings.

Feel free to view or clone the repo to try. This error is occuring in Google Chrome 26. All the code is within game.ts, gameobject.ts and main.ts, theres lots of references to outside libraries like underscore and jquery ui which I plan to spruce up the GUI a little once I get the main game logic complete.

Thank you for any who have even bothered to read all this, your help is much appreciated.

edit: so I'm trying to use a loop like this to put a "turn" in the game

```
 while (is_over)
    {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: The `while` loop makes it "work" because it completely freezes JavaScript evaluation at that point.

Comment: Also multi-line strings like that won't work in all browsers.

Comment: @Pointy the while loop is actually what causes the error to happen, not vice-versa. The multi-line string is the least of my concern right now its only gui related. I'm more concerned where the logic error may be. That is, unless there is some weird correlation between multi-line strings and type errors.

Comment: ah - well that's ... interesting.

Comment: What is the resulting javascript

Comment: @Esailija I can post it here if you like, but since it is a typescript project, there is a .map and a compiled .js, rather than bloat this post it's all viewable on the github I linked to.

Comment: @treehau5 Well I mean like what javascript is actually run when you use `while(true) {}`?

Comment: that was just an arbitrary example. it could of been while(anything) { do_something; break; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
while(false){
 // Unreachable code
 do_something;
 break;
}
```

If what is inside the condition ie. `anything` in your case never becomes false then it is effectively `while(true)` which as mentioned by steve fenton would be stopped by browsers or crash.

A slightly better way to loop would be:

```
function loop(){
   var result = do_something();
   // Repeat 
   if (result) {setTimeout(loop,100);}
   // Break
   else return; 
}
setTimeout(loop,100);
```

Although I would recommend using a game engine instead of setTimeout. e.g http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS

Answer (score 2):

In your question you are using the following example:

```
while (true)          //removing this while loop causes above line to work fine.
{ }
```

This tight loop will prevent pretty much anything from happening (and usually the browser will ask if you want to terminate the script.

If this isn't the code you are using, please show the code you are using - ideally a shortened version that demonstrates the issue rather than an entire program. I have tested several variations of loops in TypeScript and can find no problem with a while loop.

Comment: while (is_over)
        {
            break;
        }

while (anything) { //just the fact that a while construct is here seems to cause an issue, whether it loops indefinitely or doesn't loop at all }

Comment: Try to create a short example that shows up the problem - for example, this while loop works fine: http://goo.gl/i6B1i